# Replace c# HttpWebRequest with a c++ class

Tags: http, cookies, httpwebrequest, httpclient, libcurl

We are doing a project with c# for a web crawl and submitter.
It is 'amazing' that HttpWebRequest have bugs in cookie and not support sock proxy.

It 'd be better to compile a c++ similar class/wrapper to dll to replace HttpWebRequest in c#.
Is there any similar class/wrapper? it should support cookie, proxy, file upload etc. thread safe. no need to parse html.
Libwww seem too complex to use.
Libcurl seem fine but any bug? how is performance?

Comment: How about WinInet and winhttp?

Answer (score 0):

libcurl is very a high performance transfer library. Of course it has its slew of bugs but we work hard on addressing them as soon as they are reported. libcurl is 100% open source and you can help out too in the unlikely case you actually find a bug.

libcurl doesn't parse HTML though, you'd have to find a separate library for that.